# \citeasnoun produces too many names

Tags: bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

I'm using `\citeasnoun` from the `harvard` package with the `econometrica` bibstyle.

My problem is that one of my citation has lots of authors so I'd like it to only show *Name et al. (200x)*.

I have not yet found a solution for this. I could change the whole bib entry, but I don't mind that all authors are given in the references at the end of the text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

to do the things mentioned in your question do the following:

open econometrica.bst (or better use a copy first for security reasons). Then search for "FUNCTION {format.lab.names}".

Now add the bolt part:

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
**numnames #3 >
{ s #1 "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$
" et~al." * }
{**
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "" * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
**if$
}**

numnames #3 > is the key variable to adjust for the number of authors after which the et al. function is used, in my example the number of authors is 3.
Don't forget to add the "if$ }" at the end.

Now save (probably update your Miktex FNDB) and us the bst file in your document!

See also here:

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-05/msg00099.html

where the et. al function is forced in the bibliography!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to section 2.4 of the `harvard` manual, the double-starred (!) macro version `\citeasnoun**` overrides the default citation style and always uses the abbreviated form. It seems, however, that this feature is available for the six styles *"currently available within the harvard family"* (manual, section 3.1), but not for the `econometrica` style which, according to the notes in `econometrica.bst`, was created with the help of `makebst`. The following example shows the forcing of the abbreviated citation form using the `agsm` style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{harvard}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citeasnoun**{A01}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the name in, e.g. "Baldwin, R. et al. 2003, p. 7", simply delete "{, f.}" in the following part:

numnames #3 > { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ " et~al." * }

Then it pops out Baldwin et al. 2003, p. 7